# One login form for two types of accounts and LoginRequiredMixin in django

Tags: django, mixins, django-authentication, django-login

I have one LoginForm for two types of users, until here all works fine. Issue comes when I do `LoginRequiredMixin` for any view, I dont know why but is redirecting to the success_url of the login form. Here is my LoginForm:

`form_valid` method redirect the users depends of the perms he has.

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    template_name = 'login.html'

    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.has_perm('users.is_contribuyente'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitudes-enviadas')
        if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.has_perm('users.is_professional'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/panel/inicio')        
        return super(LoginView,self).dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)


    def form_valid(self,form):
        login(self.request,form.get_user())
        if self.request.user.has_perm('users.is_contribuyente'):
            return redirect('/solicitudes-enviadas')
        if self.request.user.has_perm('users.is_professional'):
            return redirect('/panel/inicio')
```

Here my view with a `LoginRequiredMixin`:

```
class SendQuoteView(LoginRequiredMixin,VerifiedUserMixin,FormMixin,DetailView):
    login_url = '/entrar/'
    model = Request
    form_class = SendQuoteForm
    template_name = 'send_quote.html'
```

Let's say this is the URL when an not authenticated user is trying to access: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/entrar/?next=/panel/detalle-solicitud/declaracion-de-renta`. And lets says the user has perm of "`is_professional`" It supose that have to redirect to `/panel/detalle-solicitud/declaracion-de-renta` but instead of that is redirecting to `/panel/inicio/`, the URL of the instrucion of `form_valid`

New `form_valid` method only for test to getting `next` variable:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        #login(self.request, form.get_user())
        next = self.request.GET('next')
        print next
        return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
```

How can I achieve that respect the URL of the LoginRequiredMixin?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in Django that magically handles `?next=...` in the url. You have to fetch the value from `request.GET`. Note that you should not trust the value from the user - Django has an `is_safe_url` method that you can use.

```
from django.http.utils import is_safe_url

next_url = self.request.GET.get('next')
if next_url and is_safe_url(next_url, self.request.get_host()):
    # redirect to next
else:
    # redirect to fallback
```

You might find it easier to use the [built in login view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views) to handle logins. You can then create a custom view for the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting, and handle the permissions-based redirects there.

Comment: @Alasdir  I implemented it, but form_valid method cant get next variable.

Comment: There should be no problem getting the `next` variable from the `form_valid` method. Make sure you are using `self.request.GET`, I had written `request.GET` before.

Comment: It does not works, take a look of my form_valid method, what im doing wrong? Always is printing "None". I have edited my question

Comment: You have ignored my warning about checking that the url is safe - **that is a security risk**. You aren't doing anything with `next` so of course it isn't doing anything. You need to return a redirect e.g. `return redirect(next_url)`.

Comment: It would be better to use the built in login url as I recommended. It already handles the `next` argument for you. If you must do it manually in your view, it might be better to do the checking in `get_success_url` instead of `form_valid`.